# Get LINQ TO SQL to create a new file for each entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Iam in my project retriving data from my database with "LINQ TO SQL"

My problem is that LINQ to SQL have created ONE file with name "Hit.designer.css"

And this file got all my Entity/MODELS for Car,Bike,Airplane.

Is it possible that LINQ TO SQL create a new file for every Entity ?

Comment: and why is this a problem exactly? You really do not want to edit this manually

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered EntityFramework?

This framework allows you to use your database tables as entities in your code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why is that, if I may ask?